# c#, How can I read a ComboBox value in a different class than Form1

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a ComboBox in my Window application

```
namespace MyProject
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form1
 {
```

Now I want to use the selected value in my ComboBox in my HelpClass

```
namespace MyProject
{
 class HelpClass
 {
```

Something like this, but this will not work but you get the idea I hope.

```
string var;
var = comboBox1.Text;
```

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't, only the UI class should access it's controls.

You could however pass the value from the textbox into your helper class. Possibly via the constructor,

```
var helper = new HelpClass(comboBox1.Text);
```

Your helper class would look like this

```
namespace MyProject
{
    class HelpClass
    {
        private string textboxValue;

        publuc HelpClass(string value)
        {
            this.textboxValue = value;
        }
    ...
```

Then you can use `this.textboxValue` where ever you need the text in your helper class.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to be able to create my HelpClass without passing a string to it. So I need to be able to get it in some other way.

Comment: @Akjell, why would you not be able to pass it into the class? Smells like bad design.

Comment: My HelpClass is actually a state class and its parent is a Enitity, all my states have Enter, Run, Leave methods. They are design so that only one state class can exist. Its a finite state machine for my game. But this is what I ended up using anyway, I change the design of the class a little. I still think its strange that there isn't any other way to do it. But thanks a lot for your help it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make your ComboBox public in Form1 class

Comment: or just create a public property in your Form1 class that holds the combobox value.  I *think* that's considered better practice.

Comment: I tried this, public string Value1; Value1 = ComboBow1.SelectedItem.ToString();, But I could not get the value in my HelpClass by Form1 temp = new Form1(); string Test1; Test1 = temp.Barrack1;

Comment: You should create a readonly proprety in Fom1: public string Value{get{return combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString();}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property with a public getter to allow access to the data, without necessarily allowing direct access to the control.

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form1
    {
        public string VarSomething
        {
            get{ return comboBox1.Text; }
        }
...
```

Probably read a bit about "properties" and "getters" and "setters" if you're not already familiar. Also naming a variable "var" will probably be confusing if you use the keyword anywhere.

Comment: I guess some comments on the other answer already mentioned this, hopefully the example is helpful